# PyCharm Run console couldnot find a module

Tags: python, pycharm

I have import statement defined as

> `from sqlalchemy import text`

My pycharm working space does not show any red marks. And default settings shows my module with correct version. in python console I can run following without any issue

```
 from sqlalchemy import text
```

[image]

[image]

When I run my python testcase it throws;

```
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Do you have more than one interpreter?

Comment: @StephenRauch yes, But I set Correct interpreter. When clicking the module it finds init.py without any issue

Comment: Are you sure you were in the correct console?

Comment: @StephenRauch Yes PYcharm's Run console Im using..Is that wrong?

Comment: The pycharm console interpreter does not necessarily match the run configuration.

Comment: @StephenRauch How can I check that run configuration ? I checked Run configurations too, It selects correct interpreter. I attched screen shot for that too

Comment: When you start the console, and when you start running a program pycharm will generally show the path used to invoke.  Make sure the paths match.  All of this was just a way to help insure that when you tested the import at the console and it worked, that the console was using the same interpreter as your run configuration.

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm talking about Pycharm 'RUN' Console. It starts with usr/local/bin/python2.7. It is right path

Comment: There is no right or wrong. It is just easy to get confused as to which interpreter pycharm is using in a particular instance.  And thus easy to install things someplace other than where you need them installed.

Comment: which python shows /usr/local/bin/python. and packages installed in usr/local/lib/python2.7/sitepackages folder.